# Sharepoint Workspace Versus Colligo

Tags: workspace, explorer-view, offline

I used to use Colligo for SharePoint 2007 and appreciated it at the time. I also thought that groove was a great tool. I now have a customer who wants a file viewer/offline tool for SharePoint 2010 and apart from sales pitches, I can't find any good comparisons of the two?

So can someone provide me with a comparison or experiences using the two?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Workspace with Sharepoint 2010 (they just don't call it Groove anymore, even though the process that runs is still called Groove). Article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649102%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

I use it every day.